# MySql, Somar valores acumulados por data e ID

Tags: mysql, sql, banco-de-dados

Boa tarde, estou com um problema para obter um resultado relativamente comum, já vi alguns materiais falando a respeito mas nenhum se aplicou a minha necessidade específica.

Preciso do total acumulado em cada lançamento, somando todos os anteriores, levando em consideração não apenas a sequencia do lançamento mas também a data em que ele foi lançado. Observem nos exemplos a seguir que o ultimo lançamento deverá ser o primeiro a ser calculado.

Informações que tenho

---

```
Id| Descricao          | Valor   | Data      
1 | PAGAMENTO ENERGIA  |- 100.00 | 2021-01-11
2 | VENDAS DO DIA      |1500.00  | 2021-01-11
3 | SALDO INICIAL      |1000.00  | 2021-01-10
```

Resultado que consigo com o comando:

```
SELECT cm.id, 
       cm.descricao, 
       cm.valor, 
       cm.datapagamento, 
       Sum(CASE 
             WHEN cm2.tipo = 1 THEN ( cm2.valor * -1 ) 
             ELSE cm2.valor 
           END) AS Total 
FROM   conta_movimentacao AS cm 
       INNER JOIN conta_movimentacao AS cm2 
               ON cm.id >= cm2.id 
GROUP  BY cm.id;
```

---

```
Id| Descricao          | Valor   | Data       | Total
1 | PAGAMENTO ENERGIA  |-100.00  | 2021-01-11 | -100.00
2 | VENDAS DO DIA      |1500.00  | 2021-01-11 | 1400.00
3 | SALDO INICIAL      |1000.00  | 2021-01-10 | 2400.00
```

O que realmente eu preciso:

---

```
Id| Descricao          | Valor   | Data       | Total
3 | SALDO INICIAL      |1000.00  | 2021-01-10 | 1000.00
1 | PAGAMENTO ENERGIA  |-100.00  | 2021-01-11 |  900.00
2 | VENDAS DO DIA      |1500.00  | 2021-01-11 | 2400.00
```

Alguém poderia me auxiliar?

Comment: Um `ORDER BY cm.DataPagamento` não atende?

Comment: Pior que não amigo, já tentei de diversas formas.  (coloquei as 3 tabelas organizadas na pergunta mas por algum motivo não ficou...)

Comment: "Running Total" com window functions    https://popsql.com/learn-sql/mysql/how-to-calculate-cumulative-sum-running-total-in-mysql

Comment: É um sistema contábil, essa modelagem não é adequada. Teria ao menos que ter uma tabela identificando as contas e outra com os lançamentos utilizando o método de partidas dobradas para ai então seguir o fluxo de caixa e montar balanços periódicos.

Comment: @motta Consegui resolver com sua dica amigo!, Obrigado.

Answer (score 2):

Graças ao comentário do @Motta consegui resolver a questão.

User a função: "sum(cm.Valor) OVER (order BY cm.DataPagamento rows between UNBOUNDED PRECEDING and current row) as Saldo" e consegui o retorno que esperava.

Obrigado pela força!

Comment: Descobri agora que a função "OVER" não funciona no MySql <= 5.7. Alguém tem alguma outra ideia?